# Is it foolish to make alexandria:curry not necessarily use funcall?

Tags: common-lisp, currying, lisp-2

Currently a function curried with Alexandria's `curry` must be called with `funcall`. However it is possible to set the new function's `symbol-function` so that we can do without it and treat it like a real function. Illustrated on https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/functions.html#with-the-alexandria-library:

```
(defun adder (foo bar)
  "Add the two arguments."
  (+ foo bar))

(defvar add-one (alexandria:curry #'adder 1) "Add 1 to the argument.")

(funcall add-one 10)  ;; => 11

(setf (symbol-function 'add-one) add-one)
(add-one 10)  ;; => 11
;; and still ok with (funcall add-one 10)
```

Is there a good reason not to allow both styles ? This looks quite interesting to me in this context of currying.

ps: I did ask on Alexandria's issue tracker some 3 weeks ago

pps: https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/alexandria/alexandria/blob/master/functions.lisp#L116

Comment: Care to explain the downvote ?

Comment: Why is the question so specifically targetted at `alexandria:curry`? It only return a closure and does not influence what you do with the result. Is your question about whether `(setf symbol-function)` should be used to define global functions? Or do you want to change `alexandria:curry` so that it changes the global binding of an additional symbol parameter?

Comment: "It only return a closure and does not influence what you do with the result": that may be my answer. Yes I was wondering why alexandria, in this context of currying where calling a function without funcall *seems* the logical way, doesn't set the binding of what it returns. But since it returns only a closure, I get it. Now, I wonder why there is no function that does that, but that's another point. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment, and looking at [the issue](https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/alexandria/alexandria/issues/3), yes it would be "foolish" to change `curry` so that it binds functions in the global namespace:

- This would be a major change for `curry`, which would break existing code
- A macro with this functionality would not mesh well with the spirit of [*Alexandria*](https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/), as far as I know. This would be better suited for [*Serapeum*](https://github.com/TBRSS/serapeum), which happens to already define such a function, namely [`defalias`](https://github.com/TBRSS/serapeum/blob/master/definitions.lisp#L136). As you can see, the definition is a little more involved than using `symbol-value`. See also the [documentation](https://github.com/TBRSS/serapeum#binding-values-in-the-function-namespace).

Comment: very insightful, and nice discovery of Serapeum. Thanks !

Comment: I'm glad to find a `defalias`, going to use it in place of some code.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, this simple macro does the job:

```
(defmacro defcurry (name function &rest arguments)
  "Returns a regular function, created by currying FUNCTION with ARGUMENTS."
  `(let ((closure (alexandria:curry ,function ,@arguments)))
     (setf (symbol-function ,name) closure)))
```

Example:

```
(defun adder (x y) (+ x y))
(defcurry 'add2 #'adder 2)
(add2 3)  ;; no "funcall" here
;; => 5"
```

*edit*: but… this is much simpler:

```
(defun add2 (a)
  (adder 2 a))
```